# Framework7 ajaxs call returns error and status of 0

Tags: c++, cordova, arduino, html-framework-7

I am creating an application that will send commands to an ESP32 over Wifi. I am using framework7 ajax calls. The problem is that when the ajax command is called, the command gets executed on the ESP32, but the response that I receive is an error.
This is my ajax code for the application.

```
 const ip = $("#sqlip").val().trim();
                //const ip = "192.168.0.8";
                console.log(ip)
                console.log('http://' + ip + ':8080/Test')

                app.request({
                    url: 'http://' + ip + ':8080/Test',
                    async: false,
                    method: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',
                    contentType: 'text/plain',
                    error: function(xhr, status, message) {
                        console.log('error')
                        //console.log(xhr)
                        console.log(status)
                        console.log(message)
                    },
                    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                        console.log(status)
                        console.log(data)
                    },
                    complete: function(xhr, status) {
                        console.log('done')
                        console.log(xhr)
                        console.log('done:' + status)
                    }

                })
```

This is the code snippet that is handling the request from the application. In the serial console, I can see the message "Test Connection Sent" So I know that the application is sending to the ESP32, but the application is getting an error when trying to receive a response.

```
server.on("/Test", handleTest); 
    void handleTest(){
     Serial.println("Test Connection Sent");
     server.send(200, "text/json", "{\"Message\": \"Test Connection\"}");
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: What errors do you have on client in console?

Comment: @AlexeyVictorov On the client I am not getting any errors, but on the application side when I run the application in browser, I get the following “Access to XMLHttpRequest at ‘http://192.168.0.8:8000/Test’ from origin ‘http://localhost:8015’ has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response” now I know that the IP url is the esp32 device and localhost is the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser is blocking requests because it is CORS enabled and doesn't receive correct headers from your server.

At server-side you need to send valid CORS headers. There are some examples for ESP32. See here for [GET](https://www.mischianti.org/2020/07/15/how-to-create-a-rest-server-on-esp8266-or-esp32-cors-request-option-and-get-part-4/) and [POST](https://www.mischianti.org/2020/07/26/how-to-create-a-rest-server-on-esp8266-or-esp32-cors-request-option-and-post-part-5/).

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will give this a try.